# PyQt and PyQtGraph library. qtgui.QGraphicsObject vs pyqtgraph.GraphicsObject

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm not sure I understand how these work (I'm not even sure if I should talk about *these* or *this*). I was reading pyqtgraph examples and found a call to a "GraphicsObject". Looked it up in pyqtgraph's documentation and it seems like they have their own QGraphicsObject class. Is that correct?

I can't manage to import the *correct* GraphicsObject (amongst others, like GraphicsItem and such; just using that class as an attempt to explain myself better). I've reinstalled the library so it has nothing to do with it, so... what I'm missing? I apologize in advance if the question is silly.

Example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

g = pg.GraphItem()
```

Error displayed about GraphItem in PyCharm:

> Cannot find reference 'GraphItem' in '**init**.py'
>
> The inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

***I found what was causing me the trouble**. It looks like scipy didn't install correctly although it didn't give me back an error, so I just had to install it in a different way.

Comment: I'm not really clear about what your question is. `pg.GraphicsObject` is a subclass of `QGraphicsObject`; how are you trying to import that? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yeah, I'm really sorry for the weird question; I just don't know how to word it properly. AFAIK pg.GraphicsObject is a subclass of QGraphicsObject, with extra methods and I've tried to import that, and others, in the same way as it's done in the examples, but the classes simply aren't there. I've looked for them using the little visual aid my IDE has (PyCharm) and tried from different *packages* and nothing worked. IIRC I just used the Q*superclasses and moved on because it didn't affect me, but I'm still curious about what am I doing wrong.

Comment: There's just not enough information for this question. You need to be more specific--what does "tried to import that" mean (show _code_)? What does "simply aren't there" mean (show _errors_)?

Comment: Thank you, I found the issue. I guess I was a little frustrated at the time and didn't read properly the console error display (this one isn't clear enough for me). I'm sorry for the trouble, thank you again for your time. Hope someone will find this useful in the future.